# Removing duplicates for a row with duplicates in one column dynamic data

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, excel-2010

I am attempting to remove duplicates for Column D for dynamic data with no headers or identifying features.  I am attempting to delete all the rows where there are duplicates for Column D.  I am converting excel to a dataframe, removing duplicates and then putting it back into excel.  However I keep getting an assortment of errors or no duplicates removed.  I am from a VBA background but we are migrating to Python

Attempted:

```
df.drop_duplicates(["C"])

df = pd.DataFrame({"C"})
df.groupby(["C"]).filter(lambda df:df.shape[0] == 1)

As well an assortment of other variations.  I was able to do this in VBA with one line.  Any ideas why this keeps causing this issue.


\\ import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"C"]})
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[''C'], keep=False)


DG=df.groupby([''C'])   
print pd.concat([DG.get_group(item) for item, value in DG.groups.items() if len(value)==1])
```

I was able to do this in VBA with one line.  Any ideas why this keeps causing this issue.

Code itself Template-

```
df = pd.read_excel("C:/wadwa.xlsx", sheetname=0)
columns_to_drop = ['d.1']
#columns_to_drop = ['d.1', 'b.1', 'e.1', 'f.1', 'g.1']


import pandas as pd


Df = df[[col for col in df.columns if col not in columns_to_drop]]
print(df)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/dadwa/dwad.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
print(df)
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Documents/Book1.xlsx", sheetname=0)

import pandas as pd
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[df.columns[3]], keep=False)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users//Documents/Book2.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
print(df)
```

Comment: ned assign back `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['C'], keep=False)`

Comment: @jezrael It really does not like that code.  Huge error when I put that in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need assign back and select 4.th columns by position:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[df.columns[3]], keep=False)
```

Comment: The data set remains unchanged.  I'll post the image.

Comment: Are data confidental? If no, can you send me your file to my email in my profile? Because it seems some data depedent problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have put code in question instead of externalised links are likely to break.  I have seen others do this quite a lot but suffice to say I should not mimic others bad habits.

Comment: If values are not removed, there is problem in data. So check whitespaces, or another difference. Hard to idetify your problem if I have no your data :(

Comment: I am using windows 10 64 bit and my code is at the end of the question.  It has text in excel, converts it to dataframe, duplicate removal and then writes it to a seperate excel workbook.  I will print to see if there are any errors there.  I don't think its removing duplicates at all according to print.

Comment: I see it now. first column is not count, because index, so need `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[df.columns[2]], keep=False)` - check 3.rd column.

Comment: I've retested that a few times and got some weird results.  Reset everything and output does not change.

Comment: Yes, it is correct output. Because parameter `keep=False` ir removed both rows with `D` values.

Comment: First row are columns and first column is called index, so untouched.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/OIzqD It tends to remove both e values in Column B.  It also has created gaps.

Comment: Hmmm, then reason should be some whitespaces like `df = pd.DataFrame({'b':['e','e',' ', ''],'c':['e','f','g', 'h']})`, check it by `(df.drop_duplicates('b', keep=False))`

Comment: My ideal output is to have Column C duplicates removed and the data rows beside it removed as well so that the data is nice, neat and usable.  This  is not behaving as I'd like.

Comment: An entire column was removed.  This is very strange indeed.

Comment: It check only column `C` then for function `drop_duplicates` another columns are not relevant, so it seems need some complicated solution, not only drop_duplicatates

Comment: Something like: df.append([df_try]*5,ignore_index=True) to append data for column C to top of Row so no gaps as well as a.loc[a.shift(-1) != a] to remove the rows adjacent duplicates removed for column C.  Not working so far but I know this can be done.

Comment: Not sure if understand, can you change `df = pd.DataFrame({'b':['e','e',' ', ''],'c':['e','f','g', 'h']})` what are you talking about? And can you add deired output?

Comment: I can do better, I can show you what I am seeing- https://ibb.co/jEQjSb

Comment: So what is desired output? Not sure if understand.

Comment: This is generally what I am trying to achieve - https://ibb.co/f08Dnb .  The goal is to remove duplicates in Column D + Rows so that it looks like in the image.

Comment: So need only forst duplicated value? Then need only `(df.drop_duplicates('b', keep='first'))` or `(df.drop_duplicates('b'))` what is same. If need keep last value `(df.drop_duplicates('b', keep='last'))`

Comment: The data is quite large and there are lots of duplicates in that Column.  So I want to remove all duplicates in Column D and the rows adjacent as seen in the image.

Comment: Yes, so `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[df.columns[2]])` should working perfectly.

Comment: I am interested in Column 4 or D in this case.  That did appear to be correct.  I'm not sure why though as that's for Column 3 is it not?  I will try this with other data and see.

Comment: Turns out even freshly created excels can become easily corrupted.  I suppose that tends to happen when you run a lot of different python code on them.  Thanks for all your help.  I should have sent you the file earlier on, but alls well ends well.

Comment: It appears to remove all duplicates save 2.  Wonder why that is.